# What is a Distance Sensitive Data how it Differs from other Data? Any Examples will be helpful

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

i was reading about Classification Algorithm KNN and came across with one term Distance Sensitive Data. I was not able to Found what exactly is Distance Sensitive Data wha are it's classifications, How to say if our Data is Distance-Sensitive or Not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that **x**<sub>i</sub> and **x**<sub>j</sub> are vectors of observed features  in cases i and j. Then, as you probably know, kNN is based on distances ||**x**<sub>i</sub>-**x**<sub>j</sub>||, such as the Euclidean one.

Now if **x**<sub>i</sub> and **x**<sub>j</sub> contain just a single feature, individual's height in meters, we are fine, as there are no other "competing" features. Suppose that next we add annual salary in thousands. Consequently, we look at distances between vectors like (1.7, 50000) and (1.8, 100000).

Then, in the case of the Euclidean distance, clearly salary feature dominates height and it's almost like we are using the salary feature alone. That is,

||**x**<sub>i</sub>-**x**<sub>j</sub>||<sub>2</sub> ≈ |50000-100000|.

However, if the two features actually have similar importance, then we are doing a poor job. It is even worse if salary is actually irrelevant and we should be using height alone. Interestingly, under weak conditions, our classifier still has nice properties such as universal consistency even in such bad situations. The problem is that in finite samples the performance is our classifier is very bad so that the convergence is very slow.

So, as to deal with that, one may want to consider different distances, such that do something about the scale. Commonly people standardize (set the mean to zero and variance to 1) each feature, but that's not a complete solution either. There are various proposals what could be done (see, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Metric_learning)).

On the other hand, algorithms based on decision trees do not suffer from this. In those cases we just look for a point where to split the variable. For instance, if salary takes values in [0,100000] and the split is at 40000, then Salary/10 would be slit at 4000 so that the results would not change.

Comment: Thanks for such well explanation. I have some doubts:   1.So by using StandardScaler this Problem can be resolved. Right?

Comment: @AmandeepSingh, it is likely to help, but doesn't necessarily solve the problem completely. Suppose that we have two standardized features x1 and x2. Suppose further that we are dealing with a regression problem and the true model is linear and is given by y=50x1+x2+u. Hence, even when the scale of x1 and x2 is the same, x1 is 50 times "more important". However, by looking at the Euclidean distance between (x1,x2) we will treat them equally and performance will suffer.

Comment: So taking above true model example what will be a right approach?

Comment: Instead of the standard Euclidean distance, using weighted ones, but the problem is that one never knows the correct weights. As I said in the answer, "There are various proposals what could be done". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Metric_learning for a couple of examples. There are many more.